# Yahoo Financial Stock info data loading into Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to load stock info data into pandas. Code

```
    import yfinance as yf
    abb = yf.Ticker("ABB.NS")
    # get stock info
    abb.info
```

How do i load abb.info data into pandas. Please throw some lights on this?

Comment: Can you provide some more detail? Have you tried anything? Stack Overflow is not a free code-writing service.

Answer (score -1):

If you only want to convert the dict to pandas dataframe you can do it as follows:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(abb.info, orient='index')
```

Generally I would recommend you to use the pandas_datareader pibrary for this task.

check the following code taken from [1].
pandas dataframe available at [2]

```
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import yfinance as yf
yf.pdr_override() # <== that's all it takes :-)
# download dataframe
data = pdr.get_data_yahoo("SPY", start="2017-01-01", end="2017-04-30")
```

[1] https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance

[2] https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader

Comment: I don't want pricing details. if you try abb.info will get PE ratio, marketcap and other info with JSON format. I was not able to convert the those info into dataframe.

Comment: I tried pd.DataFrame(list(abb.info.items())) . This works well

Comment: Ok then, you don't need to convert it to list, pandas has a better way. check the updated answer.